# Pass value from fragment to Helper class

Tags: android

How can I pass spinner value from fragment to any helper class?

Pass **text**

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

to **valueHere**

```
public FirebaseDatabaseHelper() {
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    final String month_name = month_date.format(instance.getTime());
    final String currentYear = String.format("%02d", instance.get(Calendar.YEAR));


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReferenceTujuan = mDatabase.getReference(valueHere);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call of the function where you get the value out of the spinner from the user you will need to pro-grammatically set it to your default value or the first value in your case.

`yourspinner.setSelection(first_item);`

Do this inside the function where you get the spinner data from the user to reset it.